# Find $2 \times 2$ submatrix with sum greater than $3n$ in a $n \times n$ matrix whose sum is $n^3$

Tags: matrices

> Let $n \ge 3$ be a positive integer.
>
> Inside a $n$ × $n$ array there are placed $n^2$ positive numbers
>   with sum $n^3$.
>
> Prove that we can find a square $2$ × $2$ of $4$ elements of the array, having the sides parallel with the sides of the array, and for which the sum of the elements in the square is greater than $3n$.

---

Here's my attempt:

Case 1: Assuming all elements as equal.
Visualising the $n$ x $n$ array as a square matrix, we have,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
     n & n & n & \cdots & n \\
     n & \color{red}{n} & \color{red}{n} & \cdots & n \\
n&\color{red}n&\color{red}n&\cdots&n\\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     n & n & n & \cdots & n    
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Clearly the sum of all elements is $n^3$.  Moreover the sum of elements in any $2$ x $2$ matrix is $4n \gt 3n$.

Case 2: Unequal numbers.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
     n_{11} & n_{12}  & \cdots& n_{1n}\\
     n_{21} & n_{22}  & \cdots &n_{2n} \\
     \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     n_{n1} & n_{n2} &  \cdots & n_{nn}   
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Although the numbers are unequal, it is given that they will add up to $n^3$. Hence the *total weight* of the matrix remains constant. Now let's try to shift the individual weights.

- Shift the weights of one $2$ x $2$ region such that the weight of that region adds up to  less that $3n$.
- This implies the weights of the rest of $2$ x $2$ regions either remain the same or is increased.
- Since weights of the other regions can either be increased or remain the same, there *has* to be at least one region greater than $3n$.

Hence my proof. Is there a more mathematical approach to this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow your proposed "shifting" strategy. Are you sure it works? How would your strategy work for a $3{\times}3$ matrix?

Comment: Are you able to adapt Test123's solution for the case where $n$ is even to handle the case where $n$ is odd?

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ denote the sum of all elements of the matrix. By assumption $S=n^3$.
By contradiction assume that each $2\times 2$ sub-matrix has sum of its 4 elements less than $3n$.

---

Assume that $n$ is even.
Then we can divide the matrix into $\frac{n}{2}\times\frac{n}{2}$ disjoint submatrices of size $2\times 2$. Hence we have that:
$$
S \leq \frac{n^2}{4} 3n=\frac{3n^3}{4}<n^3
$$
which is a contradiction.

---

Now assume that $n$ is odd. Can you proceed analogously?

Comment: In case $n=4$ there exist $9$ submatrices ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I mean disjoint submatrices of size $2\times 2$. I didn't say that the total number of $2\times 2$ submatrices is $n^2/4$.

Comment: @Test123 -- Very nice!